# Installing rtree==0.9.4 in Macbook Pro M1 Monterey

Tags: python, macos-monterey, r-tree

I'm currently trying to install the version 0.9.4 of rtree in Python3.7.9. However, I keep getting the following error. Still, I can install any version of rtree>=0.9.5. The problem is that I really need version 0.9.4.

```
Collecting rtree==0.9.4
  Using cached Rtree-0.9.4.tar.gz (62 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/paulonascimento/Desktop/nooo/pychop3d-master/venv/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/1g/t90pxf4x4rzdypyz5jybl9yw0000gn/T/pip-install-imj0pc0j/rtree_77886c1cf36d47a8aa2bef7aa1b5267f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/1g/t90pxf4x4rzdypyz5jybl9yw0000gn/T/pip-install-imj0pc0j/rtree_77886c1cf36d47a8aa2bef7aa1b5267f/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/1g/t90pxf4x4rzdypyz5jybl9yw0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-uk6yo3dc
       cwd: /private/var/folders/1g/t90pxf4x4rzdypyz5jybl9yw0000gn/T/pip-install-imj0pc0j/rtree_77886c1cf36d47a8aa2bef7aa1b5267f/
  Complete output (15 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/1g/t90pxf4x4rzdypyz5jybl9yw0000gn/T/pip-install-imj0pc0j/rtree_77886c1cf36d47a8aa2bef7aa1b5267f/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
      import rtree
    File "/private/var/folders/1g/t90pxf4x4rzdypyz5jybl9yw0000gn/T/pip-install-imj0pc0j/rtree_77886c1cf36d47a8aa2bef7aa1b5267f/rtree/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
      from .index import Rtree
    File "/private/var/folders/1g/t90pxf4x4rzdypyz5jybl9yw0000gn/T/pip-install-imj0pc0j/rtree_77886c1cf36d47a8aa2bef7aa1b5267f/rtree/index.py", line 6, in <module>
      from . import core
    File "/private/var/folders/1g/t90pxf4x4rzdypyz5jybl9yw0000gn/T/pip-install-imj0pc0j/rtree_77886c1cf36d47a8aa2bef7aa1b5267f/rtree/core.py", line 143, in <module>
      rt.Error_GetLastErrorNum.restype = ctypes.c_int
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 377, in __getattr__
      func = self.__getitem__(name)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 382, in __getitem__
      func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
  AttributeError: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, Error_GetLastErrorNum): symbol not found
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/6f/f1e91001d5ad9fa9bed65875152f5a1c7955c5763168cae309546e6e9fda/Rtree-0.9.4.tar.gz#sha256=cae327e2c03b3da4ea40d0fdf68f3e55fe9f302c56b9f31e1bfeb36dbea73f44 (from https://pypi.org/simple/rtree/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rtree==0.9.4 (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.4, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.9.4, 0.9.5, 0.9.6, 0.9.7)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for rtree==0.9.4
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/paulonascimento/Desktop/nooo/pychop3d-master/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Most topics on this relate to installing libspatialindex. I've used Homebrew to install spatialindex, but I still can't install rtree==0.9.4. Should I downgrade my Python version or something like that? I also updated my pip version, as suggested in the "WARNING", but the error remains the same.